# Writing a more complex Traversal (Lenses)

Tags: haskell, traversal, haskell-lens

I'm diving continually deeper into Kmett's lenses; today I'm attempting to write some custom traversals, up until now I've managed to get along by composing existing traversals to create new ones, but I'm doing something a little more complicated and got stuck.

I'm writing a text editor and I'm just adding multiple cursors, originally each buffer had one cursor and had a lens to focus it, now I'm generalizing to a list of cursors and want a traversal over the list. The trick is that in the previous case my lens did some validation inside the setter to ensure that a cursor was clamped to fit within the valid range of the buffer's text. It looked like this:

```
clampCursor :: Text -> Cursor -> Cursor

cursor :: Lens' Buffer Cursor
cursor = lens getter setter
  where getter buf = buf^.curs
        setter buf new = let txt = buf^.text
                          in buf & curs .~ clampCursor txt new
```

Note how it uses the text info from the context of the buffer to create a lens over the cursor; (Also I'd love to hear about any cleaner ways to do this instead of making custom lenses if anyone has suggestions, I've found myself doing it a lot).

So now that I've got multiple cursors I need to transform this into a Traversal', but of course I can't define a traversal using the `lens getter setter` method; Looking around for how to define traversals I read this [tutorial](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-tutorial-1.0.2/docs/Control-Lens-Tutorial.html#g:5); Which states the following:

> Question: How do I create traversals?
>
> Answer: There are three main ways to create primitive traversals:
>
> - traverse is a Traversal' that you get for any type that implements Traversable
> - Every Lens' will also type-check as a Traversal'
> - You can use Template Haskell to generate Traversal's using makePrisms since every Prism' is also a Traversal' (not covered in this tutorial)

None of those methods really help out here; I've also seen the style where you create a traversal using applicative style, but it's always been a bit confusing to me and I don't really know how I would use it in this case to get what I want.

I suppose I could write a `Lens' Buffer [Cursor]` which maps over the cursors in the setter to perform the validation and THEN traverse that list, but I figure there's got to be a way to bake it into the traversal AFTER the traverse (when each single element is focused) somehow. Maybe there's a better way to do this entirely;

Still looking to learn as much as I can about traversals, so any explanations are appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT:
@dfeuer pointed out that when you do this sort of validation you end up with invalid lenses, I really like the clean interface it provides to do them inside the lens; and so far as I know, since the validation is idempotent it shouldn't cause any real issue, but I'm open to suggestions on how to do this better.

Comment: You already have a bit of a problem: thanks to the clamping, your `Lens` is not quite a law-abiding lens. Can you give some more information about what a `Cursor` is and how it's used? Your current setup feels a bit odd to me. I don't tend to think of a cursor as being "part of" a buffer. I suspect what you may really want is something more like a collection of lens-like "pointers" into a buffer.

Comment: Hrmm, I suppose that's true; is there a better way to do validation where the interface is clean but law abiding? I've always thought of setters as where validation should be performed. Basically a cursor is an offset into the file that keeps track of where future operations should be performed e.g. deleting characters, inserting text, etc. 'Buffer' in this case refers to the Vim terminology of a representation of editable text. In my case each buffer has a set of cursors in it.

I'd love to do everything using lens-like pointers, but you break other lens laws when you try to do that :P

Comment: I'd also like to do some more transformations over the list of cursors when it's set; for instance I'd like to sort them and remove duplicates as well.

Comment: Do you want them to always be sorted and unique? If so, the buffer conceptually becomes a list of `Text` segments, with cursors implicitly between them. It's quite possible to make a law-abiding `Setter` perform validation, because setters have almost no laws. Lenses are a different beast.

Comment: One thing you might consider is using a phantom type to tag a buffer and its cursors. So a `Cursor s` will be *known* in-bounds for a `Buffer s`; you can create cursors using `Prism`s. The `s` can also reify the buffer size (see `Data.Reflection` in the `reflection` package).

Comment: Instead of having lenses, you could split the buffer at the cursor's position and have "before cursor" and "after cursor" parts (or a list of parts, in case of multiple cursors). A bit like a zipper http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers. But perhaps this doesn't play well with other aspects of the program.

Comment: I suppose I should mention that the primary focus of the editor is to be as modular and extensible as possible; to that end I'm implementing EVERYTHING as extensions (including cursors). Because of that I can't actually change the way that the text is stored, all cursor state has to be external. (though those are really cool ideas!)
https://github.com/chrispenner/rasa

Comment: I figure I should mention that a *usefully* extensible system needs to be built on a sufficiently capable framework. You need done fundamental abstractions everyone can agree on. For an editor, I think cursors are sufficiently important to bake in.

Comment: One other key feature that you probably want to think about in the base later is undo history. If you don't give that enough attention early on, you could paint yourself into a corner. In particular, consider whether you might ever want to save and restore undo histories.

Comment: I appreciate the design suggestions, but I have a few ideas for how to handle those things :) The whole thing's a bit of an experiment, it's surprising how much you can do with a good extension api, for instance even the renderer and file-system access are abstracted into extensions.

At the moment I'm mostly looking to handle this Traversal problem, Undo states are a problem for another day :)

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake. You *can't* do checks in a law-abiding setter either, because of the setter functor laws! `over cursor (retreat . advance) = over cursor id` won't hold if it advances too far. I'm not at all surprised that rendering and FS access work as plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is to use the `Functor` / `Applicative` representation of lenses directly for doing this sort of thing.

To write a non-type-changing (simple) `Lens` or a `Traversal`, you need to write a function that takes as arguments a function `k :: a -> f a` and your structure `s` and then produces a `f s`.

`k` is kind of a generalized modification function, which represents the change that an user of the lens wants to make to the data focused by the lens. But because `k` is not simply of type `a -> a`, but instead of type `a -> f a`, it also allows to carry a "result" out of the update, for example, the value of the field before it was updated (if you use the state monad for f, then you can set the state to the field's old value in the update function and read it out when you run the state monad afterwards).

Our approach in the following code is to change this modification function, to perform some clamping before returning the new value:

```
-- Takes a cursor update function and returns a modified update function 
-- that clamps the return value of the original function
clampCursorUpdate :: Functor f => Text -> (Cursor -> f Cursor) -> (Cursor -> f Cursor)
clampCursorUpdate k = \cur -> fmap (clampCursor txt) (k cur)
```

We can then turn a non-validating lens into a validating lens (note that as said in the comments, this validating lens is not a law-abiding lens):

```
-- assuming that _cursor is a lens that accesses
-- the _cursor field without doing any validation
_cursor :: Lens' Buffer Cursor

cursor :: Functor f => (Cursor -> f Cursor) -> Buffer -> f Buffer
cursor k buffer = _cursor (clampCursorUpdate txt k) buffer
 where txt = buffer^.text
```

This approach is easy to generalize to traversals. First, we write the non-validating traversal by composing a `Lens' Buffer [Cursor]` with `traverse`, which will turn that into a `Traversal' Buffer Cursor`:

```
-- assuming that _cursors is a lens that returns the list of cursors
_cursors :: Lens' Buffer [Cursor]

-- non-validating cursors traversal
_cursorsTraversal :: Traversal' Buffer Cursor
_cursorsTraversal = _cursors . traverse
```

Now we can use the same approach as we did earlier: since the traversal already does the "mapping" for us, the code is the same, except that we now have an `Applicative f` constraint on our `f`, because we want a `Traversal'`:

```
cursors :: Applicative f => (Cursor -> f Cursor) -> Buffer -> f Buffer
cursors k buffer = _cursorsTraversal (clampCursorUpdate txt k) buffer
 whee txt = buffer^.text
```

Answer (score 0):

As `curs :: Lens' Buffer Cursor` becomes `curs :: Lens' Buffer [Cursor]`, your task of constructing a law-disregarding `cursor :: Traversal' Buffer Cursor` can be split into constructing a law-disregarding `Lens' Buffer [Cursor]` that does bounds checks, and turning any `Lens' s [a]` into a `Traversal' s a`.

The first could have been solved by you: You do what you've already been doing, but check bounds on each element of the `[Cursor]`.

The second is a law-abiding request and thus you could have expected an answer without that torrent of comments under your post:

```
turnIntoTraversal :: Lens' s [a] -> Traversal' s a
turnIntoTraversal l = l . traverse
```

Also for my fun here's an attempt at a direct implementation.

```
cursor :: Traversal' Buffer Cursor
cursor atofa s = (curs . traverse) (fmap (clampCursor $ s ^. text) . atofa) s
```